# Is it possible to setup a router to access local computers available on RJ45 which is connected to WAN port

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I have a router which has 4 LAN and a WAN ports. I use PPPoE to connect internet. Earlier i used to connect internet via my Laptop. Since I started using router, i could not see local computers (reason is obvious) my laptop is connected through LAN port of router and not to actual ISP LAN cable. WAN has internet IP not local network IP.

Is it possible to connect local computers (without switch) so that I can use IPmessanger with my friends ? if yes how?

Please advice

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. Configure your ISP access data on the router and let it handle the internet connection?

Comment: My ISP provides RJ45 connection when i connect it to my computer, I can connect with my friends play cs etc. as they are on the same network 192.169.100.X. However,  for using router I need to insert RJ45 into WAN port. which gets  WAN IP from ISP.  Hence I do not have access to local computers ie network 192.168.100.X. My query is, is there any way configuration or something to bridge WAN and LAN ports so that i can access 192.168.100.x
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Configure your router accordingly. The idea behind a (home) router is that you have a device which lets your share the WAN connection between multiple other devices and router traffic accordingly. You connect your ISPs cable to the WAN port and every computer that should be part of the network to one of the available LAN ports.

Every computer gets some kind of internal address like `192.169.100.X` usually automatically assigned using DHCP. That DHCP configuration also supplies additional information e.g. that your router should be the default gateway for those computers. That was traffic that isn't meant for the internal network gets send to the router and the router forwards it to your ISP.

If you can not ping or otherwise reach the other computers that are part of your LAN (assuming they're all connected to the LAN ports of the router) you need to check the configuration for isolation options. This depends on the model of the router so without knowing which model of router it is you're on your own on that.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Other computers are not on my router's LAN. they are on ISPs network.
my router is tp-wr740n. Also, I have flashed it with DD-WRT.

Comment: `Since I started using router, i could not see local computers` so you suddenly don't have any local computers anymore? What do you mean they're on your ISPs network? In that case they should have an internet IP and you'd use that?